# Can I "undope" an extrinsic semiconductor?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

If I have either a p-type or n-type semiconductor, will it be possible to "undope" it, like bring it back to a regular pure semiconductor? Of course there is the simple but energy-extensive way of simply melting the silicon and subsequent purification, but I am looking for an easier process.

What I am thinking is that maybe if we diffuse pure silicon into a doped silicon, the newcoming silicon atoms would replace the dopant atoms, but I am not so sure.

Motivation: I came to this question as I was reading about recycling e-wastes. Most of the silicon in e-wastes would already be doped, so it wouldn't be if much use unless we could undope it, and possibly be redoped as per the manufacturer's wish whoever got hold of the recycled silicon.

Comment: Not possible.  Impurity atoms are added to pure silicon atoms to create n-type an p-type.  You are talking about an interlinked atomic structure.

Comment: It would be possible, if you melt it or do some kind of heat treatment. For Si: P or less common As, which are used for n-doping will evaporate faster than Si. B, which is commonly used for p-type doping will probably stay. Yet, Si is so cheap that this process is probably not paying off. At least not at the moment.

Comment: @engineer Maybe silicon is pretty cheap, but the semiconductors in LEDs are Gallium or Indium based as far as I know. It would be highly recommend to extract these compounds from broken LEDs.

Comment: It absolutely is possible. In fact, it is necessary, since all modern Si wafers are all grown as boron doped. So, to make them n-type, you have to counter dope with enough donors to overcome the background p-type. All you need is more of one dopant than the other. This was also required in earlier technologies for any vertical bipolar technologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be possible by a metallurgical method called **[Zone Refining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_melting)** if I'm not wrong. 
It's based on the fact that impurities are more soluble in the *melt* than the substance which we wish to isolate. 
Simply put, it involves rolling heaters. These heaters are made to move in a particular fashion along a column of the metalloid several times in a similar fashion. The end result is that the impurities *flow* to a particular *end* (as a result of the way in which the heaters were operated). The *end* becomes concentrated with impurities and is simply sliced off. This process can be carried out multiple times to obtain various levels of purity.

Comment: Oh wow, I haven't thought about that. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I have another question, would this work on compound semiconductors like Gallium Arsenic Phosphide? They are used in LEDs, so it would be great if we can recycle them

Comment: @PrittBalagopal I'm pretty sure this doesn't answer your follow up question, but it does make an interesting read: https://www.led-professional.com/resources-1/articles/led-lamps-recycling-technology-for-a-circular-economy

Comment: @PrittBalagopal I'm not exactly sure of the processes employed in the recycling of the stuff you've mentioned. But I've got a feeling that no one would _care_ for it until the resources are severely depleted. The industry is more profit-friendly.

Comment: Hi @PrittBalagopal and Kunal. It's not that no one cares about recycling its just that getting a break-even in the business of recycling is very difficult. See its easy to just say *Zone Refining* but do you know that purification of Si is one hell of a difficult process in practical-life especially at industrial scale. My friend at ISRO jokes that besides great technology you need "pure thoughts" if you even hope to recycle/purify Si

Comment: @aim100k Thats interesting to hear. Thank you for sharing this wonderful information.